# Ubuntu does not pick up WIFI

Tags: networking, wireless

My wifi has always worked fine on my Ubuntu desktop PC until recently.

Now, for some reason, my desktop does not pick up my wifi at home. There are no wifi networks in the drop-down menu. There is no "enable wifi"option in the drop-down menu.

My desktop does pick up a wired connection, which I'm currently using in lieu of wifi.

I should also note that my wifi works fine on my Ubuntu laptop, so it must be a problem with the desktop.

I've done a sudo-apt get upgrade. No luck. Here's a screenshot.

[image]

I should also note that this problem started after I moved and got a new ISP and router, though I don't think that's the issue, since my laptop is working fine.

Any ideas how I can resolve this? Thank you!

Comment: Any output if you hit `dmesg` in the terminal? Newly upgraded to later Ubuntu? Old NIC?

Comment: Have you tried the official troubleshooting guide? https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting-hardware-check.html

Comment: Start here https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos

Comment: @mattias yes, there's a very long output. I haven't upgraded to a later Ubuntu. What's NIC?

Comment: **Unrelated but important**: You should use the microcode. It's updated firmware for the CPU.  **Related**: It isn't clear that you tested the same WiFi (USB??) or a different one in the laptop. If using the laptop's internal, how is it relevant? If the same USB dongle *and* you're sure it's recognized in the laptop and can connect to the network then yes, you have a problem with the desktop's OS or the USB port.

Comment: *there's a very long output*... Yes, of course there is **and it's needed for troubleshooting**. The script outputs to a txt file saved at /home/user (your username, of course). The answer also tells you *where* to upload it so you can later [edit] the question and include said link. *What's NIC?*... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_interface_controller so, the question was what's your WiFi device?

Comment: I'm not sure what my wireless device is, tbh. How do I check? Should I post the dmesg output in the original question?